# Transitioning local Craft site to AWS EC2

Tags: database

First post here and I am a complete newbie when it comes to Craft and any kind of server config but I am trying to learn.

I am trying get my Craft site that I built locally up to a server today.

I followed a pretty detailed guide about setting up EC2 for craft here:
https://solspace.com/blog/spinning-up-a-craft-cms-development-site-on-amazon-ec2

The issue I'm running into is that when I go to my EC2 URL I'm getting a

> "Service Unavailable
>
> Our site is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later."

Then trying to login, I get a

> "Craft can’t connect to the database with the credentials in
>   craft/config/db.php."

With devmode on and looking at the console, its throwing me this error:

> "install:82 [16:36:40.799][error][exception.Craft\DbConnectException]
>   exception 'Craft\DbConnectException' with message 'Craft can’t connect
>   to the database with the credentials in craft/config/db.php.' in
>   /var/www/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php:855"

So clearly Craft is unable to find the database that I created locally but I'm not really sure how to fix this.

My db.php

```php
// The database server name or IP address. Usually this is 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'.
'server' => 'localhost',

// The name of the database to select.
'database' => 'mydatabasename',

// The database username to connect with.
'user' => 'root',

// The database password to connect with.
'password' => 'root',

// The prefix to use when naming tables. This can be no more than 5 characters.
'tablePrefix' => 'craft',
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to SSH into your EC2 instance and connect to MySQL with those credentials through the command line?

Comment: Yes, I was.  Figured out the issue.  I had one character off in my MySQL database versus what I was telling craft it was called in the db.php file.  User error prevails again!

Comment: It's always something like that!  Glad you're sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the issue. I had one character off in my MySQL database name versus what I was telling craft it was called in the db.php file which is why it was failing to access it. User error prevails again!